# Derivation of a log likelihood estimate for Hellinger distance or Jensen Shannon discrepancy

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Akaike derived a log likelihood estimate for Kullback Leibler discrepancy in order to get AIC.  Is it possible to use the same approach using Hellinger distance or Jensen Shannon discrepancy (i.e to derive a log likelihood estimate).  Which of the two measures will be simpler and how to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in general you can construct estimators based on different distances as long as you can write the distance as an expectation (to the best of my understanding, and so the KL divergence appears in the context of likelihood estimation). They are called [M-estimators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator) and there is a whole theory about them (see e.g., these [lecture notes](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebartlett/courses/2013spring-stat210b/notes/15notes.pdf) by Peter Bartlett).